Deleting old files + retain last 7
Require help fine tuning script
Script removes the files by date but i want to ensure that the most recent ( 7 Files ) remain regardless of date.
And perhaps email to say nothing had been done
function DeleteOldFiles() {
  var Folders = new Array(
    '1YS60U0Cts******I2Lqxb6-_TS0LMho1',   // Calllogs
    '1Vofy1iPjV******yFc11Nhmr6DnHM736',   // Messages
    '1iP-TAOAH_******6jvIuN6Pnln2w6R3g',   // Contacts
    '1kDCzGFu9d******v33PXklT7ds5B6G11',   // Calendars

  );
  var Files;

  Logger.clear();

  for (var key in Folders) {
    Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Folders[key])
    Files = Folder.getFiles();
    
    Logger.log('Opening Folder: ' + Folder.getName());

    while (Files.hasNext()) {
      var File = Files.next();
      

      if (new Date() - File.getLastUpdated() > 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
        File.setTrashed(true);  // Places the file in the Trash folder
                                //Drive.Files.remove(File.getId()); 
                                // Permanently deletes the file
        Logger.log('File ' + File.getName() + ' was deleted.');
      }
    }
  }

  if(Logger.getLog() != '')
    MailApp.sendEmail('My Email Address', 'Backups have been removed from Google Drive', Logger.getLog());
}


First gather all files, remove 7 latest files from this array, loop again and remove them

Justinas. Thanks for your reply that is well beyond my very basic knowledge

Duplicate of Google apps script to delete old files permanently and keep last 100 files
